# JavaFX TextField.setText вызывает NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, scene-builder

Пытаюсь сделать "крестики-нолики". Не получается установить на последней сцене время продолжительности игры и задний фон, соответствующий победителю. Я так понимаю, проблема тут одна и та же, однако не могу разобраться, в чем проблема.
Класс контроллер:

```
package View;
import Model.Game;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import main.ZeroX;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    protected Button startGame;
    @FXML
    protected TextField fieldSize;
    @FXML
    protected TextField winCount;
    @FXML
    protected Button initGame;
    @FXML
    protected Pane rootGameScene;
    @FXML
    protected Button retryGame;
    @FXML
    protected Button errorRetry;
    @FXML
    protected TextField gameTime;
    @FXML
    protected ImageView endGameBackground;
    protected SubScene gameField;
    private final Image imageWinX=new Image(getClass().getResource("/ZeroX_winX.jpg").toExternalForm());
    private final Image imageWinZero=new Image(getClass().getResource("/ZeroX_winZero.jpg").toExternalForm());

    public void startGame(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(fieldSize.getText());
        int win = Integer.parseInt(winCount.getText());
        if (size>3&&size<6&&win<size&&win>2) {
            Model.Game.initGame(size, win);
            ZeroX.setPrimaryStage(Utils.Resource.scenes.get("gameScene"));
        }
        else {
            ZeroX.setPrimaryStage(Utils.Resource.scenes.get("errorScene"));
        }
    }

    public void initField(){
        final GridPane field = new GridPane();
        for (int i=0; i<Model.Game.getSizeField(); i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Model.Game.getSizeField(); j++){
                Button xor0 = new Button("");
                Label test = new Label("");
                test.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                xor0.setPrefSize(100,100);
                final int finalI = i;
                final int finalJ = j;
                xor0.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        if (!Game.getGame().isGameOver()) {
                            if (Game.getCount() % 2 == 0) {
                                ImageView image = new ImageView(Game.getGame().getImageX());
                                field.add(image, finalI, finalJ);
                                Game.setField('X', finalI, finalJ);
                            } else {
                                ImageView image = new ImageView(Game.getGame().getImageZero());
                                field.add(image, finalI, finalJ);
                                Game.setField('0', finalI, finalJ);
                            }
                            Game.getGame().checkFinish(finalI, finalJ);
                            Game.setCount(Game.getCount() + 1);
                            if (Game.getGame().isGameOver()) setEndScene();//Ошибка!!!
                        }
                    }
                });
                field.add(xor0,i,j);
                field.add(test,i,j);
            }
        }
        field.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gameField = new SubScene(field,Model.Game.getSizeField()*100, Model.Game.getSizeField()*100);
        rootGameScene.getChildren().clear();
        rootGameScene.getChildren().add(gameField);
    }

//    public void setEndGameBackground(Image image){
//        endGameBackground.setImage(image);
//    }
//
//    public void setGameTime() {
//        String time = Long.toString(Game.getTimeEnd()-Game.getTimeStart());
//        gameTime.setText(time);
//    }

    public void retryGame(){
        Game.getGame().retry();
    }

    public void errorRetry(){
        try {
            Utils.Resource.loadScenes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ZeroX.setPrimaryStage(Utils.Resource.scenes.get("firstScene"));
    }

    private void setEndScene(){
        String time = Long.toString(Game.getTimeEnd()-Game.getTimeStart());
        gameTime.setText(time);  //Ошибка!!!
        if (Game.getGame().isWinIsX()) endGameBackground.setImage(imageWinX); //Ошибка!!!
        else endGameBackground.setImage(imageWinZero);
    }
}
```

FXML файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="View.Controller">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="endGameBackground" fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <Label alignment="TOP_RIGHT" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="430.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Время игры:" />
      <Button fx:id="retryGame" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="464.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#retryGame" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Еще?" />
      <TextField fx:id="gameTime" layoutX="289.0" layoutY="426.0" />
      <Separator layoutY="408.0" prefHeight="1.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Класс, подгружающий сцены:

```
package View;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Utils {

    public static class Resource {
        public static HashMap <String, Scene> scenes = new HashMap<String, Scene>();

        public static void loadScenes() throws IOException {
            Parent first = FXMLLoader.load(Controller.class.getResource("/FirstScene.fxml"));
            Scene firstScene = new Scene(first);
            Parent game = FXMLLoader.load(Controller.class.getResource("/GameScene.fxml"));
            Scene gameScene = new Scene(game);
            Parent over = FXMLLoader.load(Controller.class.getResource("/OverScene.fxml"));
            Scene overScene = new Scene(over);
            Parent error = FXMLLoader.load(Controller.class.getResource("/ERRORScene.fxml"));
            Scene errorScene = new Scene(error);

            scenes.put("firstScene", firstScene);
            scenes.put("gameScene", gameScene);
            scenes.put("overScene", overScene);
            scenes.put("errorScene", errorScene);
        }
    }
}
```

Сама ошибка:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57692:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Java\Projects\ZeroX_v1.1\target\classes;C:\Users\Derzkohlestkomobil'\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\15-ea+5\javafx-controls-15-ea+5.jar;C:\Users\Derzkohlestkomobil'\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\15-ea+5\javafx-controls-15-ea+5-win.jar;C:\Users\Derzkohlestkomobil'\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\15-ea+5\javafx-graphics-15-ea+5.jar;C:\Users\Derzkohlestkomobil'\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\15-ea+5\javafx-graphics-15-ea+5-win.jar;C:\Users\Derzkohlestkomobil'\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\15-ea+5\javafx-base-15-ea+5.jar;C:\Users\Derzkohlestkomobil'\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\15-ea+5\javafx-base-15-ea+5-win.jar" main.ZeroX
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at View.Controller.setEndScene(Controller.java:115)
    at View.Controller.access$000(Controller.java:18)
    at View.Controller$1.handle(Controller.java:77)
    at View.Controller$1.handle(Controller.java:63)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Ссылка на весь проект: https://yadi.sk/d/_p8vdAmcutytmQ
Буду очень признателен за советы по поводу оформления и оптимизации кода: это мой первый опыт на JavaFX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку нашел! Класс Utils.Resources был ни к черту - из-за того, что подгружал сцены из другого класса, не мог подключиться к контроллеру (соответственно, не мог адекватно вызывать его методы). Решил проблему вот этим:

```
        FXMLLoader overSceneLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        overSceneLoader.setLocation(ZeroX.class.getResource("/OverScene.fxml"));
        AnchorPane over = (AnchorPane)overSceneLoader.load();
        Scene overScene = new Scene(over);
        Controller overController = overSceneLoader.getController();
        overController.setEndScene();
```

Насколько я понял, тупо создавать объект контроллера (*Controller myControl = new Controller()*) абсолютно бессмысленно. Строчкой *Controller overController = overSceneLoader.getController()* мы получаем контроллер, который уже привязан к нужному нам fxml-файлу и с помощью этого экземпляра уже вызываем методы класса Controller.